# How to hide an item from nav menu on desktop view?(without plugin)

Tags: menus

so I am using elementor for developing the website and in my primary header I have the logo, Nav- menu and button. Now what I want is I want to hide a specific item of Nav-menu on desktop but make it visible on mobile view. can someone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a CSS class on the menu item, and then in the Custom CSS feature of Elementor, define the class globally: if Elementor Pro, then follow [their directions](https://elementor.com/help/global-custom-css/), otherwise, these [directions from Kinsta](https://kinsta.com/blog/elementor-custom-css/#how-to-add-custom-css-using-elementor-5-methods) may help.

```css
@media ( min-width: 768px ) {
    .hide-if-desktop {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

[image: WordPress nav menu interface]

If this doesn't work, then you'll need to identify the selector that's competing with your style, and then change your selector to be [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to override the existing style competing with yours.